# Ruby UDP server with multiple clients?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ruby, network-programming

I have been struggling with this for a while. I'm trying to create a simple UDP server that should unicast messages between two clients. The clients is one iOS  client (the receiver) and one Mac client (the sender). If I send something from the mac, currently a string, it should appear on the iOS app, which isn't the case right now. I think (or hope) that I have located the problem to the server, it currently look like this:

```
require 'socket'
@host = "0.0.0.0"
@port = 80
BasicSocket.do_not_reverse_lookup = true
# Create socket and bind to address
socket = UDPSocket.new
socket.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET,Socket::SO_BROADCAST, 1)
socket.bind(@host, @port)
while true do
  data, addr = socket.recvfrom(1024) # if this number is too low it will drop the larger   packets and never give them to you
  puts [addr[0], data]
  socket.send(data, 0, @host, addr[1])
  puts "Sender address: #{addr[1]}"
end
```

On the client side I use AsyncUdpSocket, the relevant part looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    socket = [[AsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [socket bindToPort:80 error:nil];
    [socket enableBroadcast:YES error:nil];
    [self sendMessage:@"Sent from my iPhone"];
    [socket receiveWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}

- (void)sendMessage:(NSString *)message
{        
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [socket sendData:data toHost:@"0.0.0.0" port:80 withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}

- (BOOL)onUdpSocket:(AsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag fromHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port
{
    NSString *theLine=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //Convert the UDP data to an NSString
    NSLog(@"%@", theLine);
    status.text = theLine;
    [socket receiveWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];

    return YES;
}
```

When I run the Mac and iOS client I get the following result from the server:

[image]

I.e two different addresses, now, when I send something from my iOS device (or simulator), it sends it to the server which echoes it back, but only to the sender and not the other client since they seem to have two different ports/addresses. So, how can I create a server that sends messages to multiple clients?

**Update** Now I'm trying with threads, to add new clients into new threads. But now I got the opposite problem, all clients gets the same port. My new server looks like this:

```
require 'socket'
@host = "0.0.0.0"
@port = 80
BasicSocket.do_not_reverse_lookup = true
# Create socket and bind to address
socket = UDPSocket.new
socket.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET,Socket::SO_BROADCAST, 1)
socket.bind(@host, @port)
clients = []

def broadcast(data, clients)                   
  clients.each do |client|
    puts client[1]
    puts data
    socket.send(data, 0, "#{client[0]}", client[1])
  end
end

while true
  data, client = socket.recvfrom(1024)
  Thread.new(client) do |client|
    puts "New client has joined"
    clients << client
    begin 
      loop do
        broadcast(data, clients)
      end
    rescue EOFError                                  
        client.close
        clients.delete(client)                             
        puts "client left"
    end
  end
end
```

Output:

[image]

Tips on how to fix this would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work (I think), the working server looks like this:

```
require 'socket'
@host = "0.0.0.0"
@port = 80
BasicSocket.do_not_reverse_lookup = true
# Create socket and bind to address
@socket = UDPSocket.new
@socket.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET,Socket::SO_BROADCAST, 1)
@socket.bind(@host, @port)
@clientPorts = []

def broadcast(data, clients)                   
  puts clients
  clients.each do |client|
    @socket.send(data, 0, @host, client)
  end
end

while true
  data, client = @socket.recvfrom(1024)
  Thread.new(client) do |clientAddress|
    puts "New client has joined" 
    unless @clientPorts.include? clientAddress[1]
      @clientPorts << clientAddress[1]
    end
    broadcast(data, @clientPorts)
  end
end
```